# Stopwatch in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, stopwatch

i am designing a code for a mountain bike club. The club wants a way to track their races on a stopwatch that reads out live time in milliseconds for even the closest of races. Anyone have any idea where to even start when coding this

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific with you question not "any idea where to even start coding this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand here is that you are trying to program a stopwatch which which times in MINUTES:SECONDS:MILLISECONDS?

First of all, I would look up on `import time` and make sure you have an understanding of how to use that. This might help:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time

Next, since you are mentioning Tkinter i'm sure you have a basic understanding of that.

You will need to make a basic GUI with the following:

- Start Button (Starts the timer)
- Stop Button (Stops the timer)
- Reset Button (Resets the timer)

If you need to track laps then you can export all times once the reset button is pressed into a txt file.

Make the GUI, then work on making a stopwatch without Tkinter just as a console program with those 3 commands and try to implement it with Tkinter.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post... but I was searching for simple stopwatch style example in Python and my search came up pretty empty with the exception of overcomplicated responses. Here is a really simple example that demonstrates how to use datetime as stopwatch, and this is in Python 3.7. Note that the time.sleep is just a placeholder for whatever operation you want to time, and I just chose to sleep 3.2 seconds as an example:

```
import time, datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(3.2)
dur = datetime.datetime.now() - start
print(dur)
```

Output:

```
0:00:03.200602
```

Comment: Well I think you should also mention that this is how to create a timer for counting the time it took to do a specific task.